# Stuck at.....Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes

Tags: reactjs

I recently started out with react and whenever I run npx create-react-app my-app, a my-app directory is created with just a package.json file, nothing else, and the command stops on the terminal as:

npx: installed 98 in 135.321s

Creating a new React app in C:\Users\me\Desktop\Projects\react_project\my-app.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

It just gets stuck here and nothing happens then.

Comment: Try `npm i -g yarn` and then `yarn create react-app my-app`

Comment: It shows the error that....cannot be loaded because running scripts is displayed on this system

Answer (score 0):

You should try reinstalling the node package manager (NPM), also try updating it.

If the error persists try to follow some of the following points referring to the link sent here:
https://betterprogramming.pub/what-to-do-if-create-react-app-doesnt-work-ad601b4c238